# React + Webpack Entry point not working as mentioned in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Below is the repo, I used to load a React Application
https://github.com/kannanagasamy/react-app-without-cra

Is there a way to change the way, webpack uses ./index.js to some path like './src/index.js'?

I tried using Entry point and pointed it to './src/index.js', but it's not working and webpack is still considering index.js on root folder instead of ./src/index.js

Can somebody help me, where I am going wrong in letting webpack consider index.js inside src folder as base file.

My Current Package.Json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "Webpack ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.0"
  }
```

My Current Webpack.config.file

```
module.exports={
    mode: "development", 
    entry: "./index.js", 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    target: "web",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.json'] 
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,    //kind of file extension this rule should look for and apply in test
                exclude: /node_modules/, //folder to be excluded
                use:  'babel-loader' //loader which we are going to use
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After updating entry point as mentioned below also, I couldn't able to move webpack to drive based on src/index.js

**Codes Used**

1. entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index"),
2. entry: "src/index",
3. entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
4. entry: "src/index.js"

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Can you address the issue more clearly? What is the error you got specifically?

Comment: I need to change the entry point of webpack to index.js in src folder instead of project root folder as per my project layout. As I don't have index.js in root folder, it's throwing me an error. When I place Index.js in project root folder, code is running fine.

Comment: I am using "npm run build" command, which in turn runs "webpack ." script

Comment: Why didn't you move `index.js` back to `src/index.js`?

Comment: I did it, Even then It's not considering it. After updating entry point to "src/index.js", it's still considering index.js in root folder.

Comment: Looks like I know what the issue was. I left it as the answer. Let’s check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue around the command build you use which is `webpack .`, the option `.`  is likely to mention the entry point at current dir `./index.js` and then override the one in the configuration file so what you need to move `index.js` back to `src/index.js` and resolve the `import` accordingly again. Finally update the `entry` as you did `./src/index.js` and remove `.` on as `webpack` cli.

```js
{
  build: 'webpack' // don't need to take any more extra arg
}
```